# Multiple RewriteConds / RewriteRules depending on file existence of single rule targets

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am currently working on a static website where I need the last URI-element being passed along as query-parameter **on some pages**.

All my static html pages are inside the `/pages/**/*` directory, where the paths directly correlate to the desired paths on the final website. Meaning `/products/kitchen` would require `/pages/products/kitchen.html` to be shown. If, in this example, the file `/pages/products/kitchen.html` would not exist, I would like to try `/pages/products.html` instead and pass on `kitchen` as query argument named `id` (`?id=kitchen`). There are static assets in an `/assets` directory, so files that exist should not be rewritten to the `/pages` directory at all. If there is no requested path, I would like to redirect to the default home-page. The `probe.json` rule is for liveliness-checks in a kubernetes cluster, I just kept it in there because I can not be 100% sure that it is not the culprit.

I tried to chain multiple `RewriteCond`s and `RewriteRule`s together in an `if > else if > else if > else` way, but that seems to be failing at some point. Unfortunately, those errors are very tricky to debug because there is no indication of what is happening besides the browsers `404`-error. Currently, only the rule for existing files and for the default page is working correctly. Any help on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated!

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .? - [L]

<files probe.json>
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</files>

RewriteCond pages/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond pages/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*(?=[/]))/(.*)$ pages/$1.html?id=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^$ pages/home.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem.

1. I had to use absolute paths.
2. I had to add `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` infront of the condition.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .? - [L]

<files probe.json>
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</files>

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*(?=[/]))/(.*)$ /pages/$1.html?id=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^$ /pages/home.html [L]
```